# Flyback Converter Design Help

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, design, converter, flyback

I am unsure whether I should edit on my previous question or create a new one. Please give me your feedback on the proper way of doing it here.Back to the question, I have struggled for the past few days in creating a 2 output flyback converter. Ideally, the Vo1 and Vo2 should be 12V and 8V respectively. The ideal current flow was 5A for both windings(Desired Pout = 100W) but I can't seem to get the desired result. Images are found below. As I am not allowed to post more than 2 links, the voltages that I obtained was Vo1 = 18V, Vo2 = 12V. I have based on my calculations as provided by the kind hearted people around here. I have based my calculations based on AN4137 and some design calculations by micro rohm. 
In actual fact I would like to use the UC3844 as my controller IC but Im still negotiating with the people from PSIM to grant me access to it. Hence I base my switching device with a pre design available in PSIM. Some information that I think is needed,
Transformer core based on EER40, Ae = 149mm^2, AL = 5200, Lm = 2.9mH, Leakage based on 10%, Vin range: 220 - 240V. Np min = 58.38. Fsw = 100kHz
Sorry for the long post. I hope someone can guide me along. Thank you.

**PS** thanks for the upvote, I have uploaded the voltage output
**PS** I have adjusted the flyback design

[image: FLyback Design]

.

[image: Current Waveform]

[image: Voltage Waveform]

Comment: Are those ammeters at the outputs? If so, you are shorting the outputs! Then how would you expect to get output?

Comment: If you lower the duty cycle from where you have it (p[lease state) a little bit, do voltages drop to values that you expect?

Comment: Here is an upvote, so you can post more links when required.  +1 for persistence.

Comment: @ Rohat, I tried to connect the ammeter without the shorting the output, but I guess PSIM found it as an error. Ill try again

Comment: @Andy aka, the duty max would be 0.48, the typical max for IC UC3844, hence I used that value for my calculations, should I lower it ?

Comment: The feedback would adjust the duty cycle to achieve the commanded voltage - did you calculate the output voltages on the basis of the 48% duty cycle?  Virtual ammeters would have zero resistance and would have zero voltage across them - how are you achieving the output voltages you say? You should be putting a resistor or current source as the load.

Comment: @ Kevin, the output voltages are pre determined, the duty cycle was used in my calculations. I achieved the output voltages by measuring it parallel to the caps, though it wasn't shown here

Comment: The energy put in the coupled inductors (transformers) have to go somewhere. With a fixed on-time and no load at the outputs, the voltage would keep rising until some secondary effects take over. A control circuit with feedback needs to be in place. A second issue, you cannot use two separate transformers, there is no way to keep both outputs regulated.

Comment: @ Rioraxe, Im in the midst of getting access to UC3844, will create a controller circuit plus a feedback circuit in due time. In addition, PSIM do not have inverted multi output transformer, thats why I decided to branch it out.

Comment: You need to explain what loads you have and yes, you can't just put max duty cycle on and expect some form of stable voltage without knowing what the load power is.

Comment: @ Andy aka, that is a tricky question , my prof was very passive , he just told me , "I need 2 outputs (as stated) that will generate 100watts" , powering up tv application". That's the only thing I got from him.

Comment: @ Andy aka, to be precise the loads are audio/video applications for tv